# Length of closed curve

Tags: differential-geometry

How to find  length of this closed curve? I dont know what limits should i take for the integral.
$$
  x = \cos^3t, \quad
  y = \sin^3t, \quad
  z = \cos 2t
$$

Comment: Try to use MathJax! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is the domain of the $t$ variable?

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Lengths_of_curves

Comment: t limits are not given. so its closed curve and length should be constant, isn't it? The problem is how to find t limits.

Comment: As $t$ travels through any interval of length $2\pi$, the point travels once around the curve.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to travel once around the curve. So we want to find the smallest $p$ such that $\cos(t+p)=\cos t$, $\sin(t+p)=\sin t$ and $\cos(2(t+p))=\cos 2t$ for all $t$.

You know that the pair $(\cos t,\sin t)$ travels once around the unit circle as $t$ travels through any interval of length $2\pi$, like $[0,2\pi)$. Since the cube function is one to one, the values of the pair $(\cos^3 t,\sin^3 t)$ are all different as $t$ travels through that interval. And all of $\cos^3 t$, $\sin^3 t$, and $\cos 2t$ repeat as $t$ is incremented by $2\pi$. So we travel once around the curve as $t$ travels through any interval of length $2\pi$.

Thus it is enough to integrate from $a$ to $b$, where $a$ is arbitrary and $b=a+2\pi$. The most attractive choices are $0$ to $2\pi$ and $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

**Remark:** When we go through the usual process, the expression we get magically simplifies. But one has to be a little careful. Note that $\sqrt{\cos^2 t\sin^2 t}=|\cos t\sin t|$.

Comment: You forgot $b=2\pi+a$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Thank you! Fixed.